# how do I find out if my application for global entry was approved?

Tags: global-entry

How do I find out if my application for global entry was approved. i filled out the form 3weeks ago. cant find website for my answer

Comment: from where? Online? If you don't know the website you used, how would we?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote from CBP on the matter:

> The extended partial government shutdown and the ongoing humanitarian and security crisis on our southern border has resulted in a substantial backlog of CBP's Trusted Traveler Programs (TTP) applications and renewals. Applicants for Global Entry (GE), SENTRI, NEXUS and FAST should expect significant delays in application processing times and limited appointment availability at TTP enrollment centers.
>
> If there is a change in the status of your account, such as a conditional approval or denial, you will receive an email stating to check your account for a change in status.

Here's the [link](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1360/kw/trusted%20traveller) for their full answer